# How to hide sort number in the grid header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularjs ui-grid. I sorted the 4 columns, but in my grid, I can see the sort number which I want to hide those sort number. I did not find any api configuration or solution. Thanks.
[image]

```
columnDefs: [
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    displayName: "",
                    width: '48%',
                    grouping: {groupPriority: 0},
                    sort: {priority: 0, direction: 'asc'}
                },
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    displayName: "",
                    sort: {priority: 2, direction: 'asc'}
                },
                {
                    name: 'bar',
                    displayName: "",
                    sort: {priority: 3, direction: 'asc'}
                },
                {
                    name: 'foo',
                    displayName: "",
                    sort: {priority: 1, direction: 'asc'}
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's built into the multi-column sort feature of the grid. If you want to suppress the number, you can either provide a custom header cell template for each column as documented here:

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions

Or write a CSS rule to hide the element. In this case you're lucky since the element in question has a specific class: `ui-grid-sort-priority-number`. This should do the trick.

```
.ui-grid-sort-priority-number {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: 'ui-grid-sort-priority-number' css class will hide the whole grid.

Comment: You must have typed something wrong if it hid the whole grid. That class is only used on the `<sub>` element that contains the number you want to hide.

Comment: Could you please demo it in here? http://plnkr.co/edit/TikOeNSSfEolyrdJ6Tnz?p=preview

Comment: If you put the CSS class rule above in the `main.css` file in your plnkr it will work.

Comment: It works if I do not add above css class in  <div id="grid2" ui-grid="gridOptions2" class="grid"></div>. Why we do not add this css class in  <div id="grid2" ui-grid="gridOptions2" class="grid"></div>?

Comment: How do you know we can set this css class (ui-grid-sort-priority-number)?

Comment: You don't need to add the class to your HTML. UI-Grid uses it. You just need to add it to your css.

Comment: I know because I inspected the element in Chrome dev tools (F12) and saw that the element in question had that class applied.